# Elastic Beanstalk - instance retirement

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Amazon Elastic Beanstalk app running. The instance is sheduled for retirement. Can I just stop and start the instance so it could start on new hardware?

Root device type = ebs

Load balancing and autoscaling is enabled.